# app not responding when not connected to internet and Admob integration in ListActivity?

Tags: java, android, rss

i am makinga blog app with RSS feed and unable to add Admob Ads because of class that extends ListActivity. and 2nd proble is when phone is not connected with internet it is not Responding.
i have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` in manifest file (some tricks on stackoverflow).

### MY java code

```
package com.xx.xxx;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{
    List headlines;
    List links;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,ArrayAdapter>
    {
        @Override
        protected ArrayAdapter doInBackground(Object[] params)
        {
            headlines = new ArrayList();
            links = new ArrayList();
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL("http://feelthesport.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss");
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                // We will get the XML from an input stream
                xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");
                boolean insideItem = false;

                // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
                int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    {
                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                        {
                            insideItem = true;
                        }
                        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                        {
                            if (insideItem)
                                headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline
                        }
                        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
                        {
                            if (insideItem)
                                links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                        }
                    }
                    else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                    {
                        insideItem=false;
                    }
                    eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
                }

            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (XmlPullParserException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayAdapter adapter)
        {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse((links.get(position)).toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url)
    {
        try
        {
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```